# MPMoviePlayerViewController wrong scale icon

Tags: ios

I'm using MPMoviePlayerViewController, When the scale button is clicked for the first time, the icon does not change, making the icon showing as reverse.

This error happend on Simulator and on Device.

I think this is an apple bug i created a small project to reproduce the bug, can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fd9f6sr0qedlqiy/testeMoviePlayer.zip)

[image]

The code i'm using to show the video:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:theFilePath]]; 
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerController];
```

Comment: Which version of iOS are you trying for your test?

Comment: tested in IOS 5.1 and 6.1

Comment: Is that issue in any way connected with the content you are using? Is there any more code involved initialising your MPMoviePlayer(View)Controller?

Comment: @Till I can't see why this issue is connected on the content (only if is an IOS bug) , and the this only code involving MPMoviePlayerViewController =/

Comment: There are **plenty** of bugs in connection with `MPMoviePlayerController`. Many of them are iOS version specific, some of them are specific on the order of initialising its properties and I certainly would not be surprised if some of them were content specific. I was asking those details to make sure that when I (or anybody else) tries to replicate the issue, the results were the same - hence be deterministic. So far your question states too few details to accomplish that.

Comment: @Till Ok, i just created an empty project to reproduce the issue (and updated my question). I will wait for some suggestion here on StackOverflow, beside i will submit a bug to apple.